# Mutiple conditional statement in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

how to write else if statement in the mysql query

if the string is three characters first check is a country code
if the string is five character check country name
otherwise, check city name or country name

like in this way

```
SELECT * FROM `geo_allcities` WHERE if(country_code3)='pak' 
else if(SUBSTRING(country_name, 1, 5))='pakis' 
else ( country_name LIKE'other string%' OR city_name like 'other string')
```

Answer (score 2):

No need of if statement, you can simply put `or` condition

```
SELECT * FROM `geo_allcities` 
WHERE country_code3='pak' or 
SUBSTRING(country_name, 1, 5)='pakis' or
  country_name LIKE'other string%' OR 
city_name like 'other string'
```

Comment: it's not produce desirable results when I enter country name USA  it return all cities start with usa but i want to get if user enter usa then return all usa cities

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE EXPRESSION.

For more detail, visit : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Example :

```
SELECT col1, col2, (case when (action = 2 and state = 0) 
 THEN
      1 
 ELSE
      0 
 END)
 as state from tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

First is you check the string length using the string length function for example  if(queryString.length())=5 then your query statement else if(queryString.length())=3 then your query statements, else report error.. 
Hope this solves the problem